# Setting HTTP Authentication header from middleware in ASP.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization

I have an API that uses JwtTokenAuthentication.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => ...);
```

I want the API to be able to work with an `<img>` tag to delivery an image. Currently that API is set the allow anonymous and the JWT token is passed as a query parameter. This works fine.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("OgiImage/{id:guid}")]
public IActionResult GetImage(Guid id, string token = null)
{
...
}
```

I am looking for a more elegant solution that can be reused. I would like to use custom middleware to set the authorization header of the request from the query parameter **before** it hits the Jwt middleware so that the build in authentication takes over. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

This is solution I came up with. Works like a charm.

I created a custom attribute to opt endpoints in to this feature and optionally specify the parameter name.

```
[JwtParameter("token)]
[HttpGet("OgiImage/{id:guid}")]
public IActionResult GetImage(Guid id, string token = null)
{
...
}
```

And then the middleware itself.

```
public class TokenQueryParameterMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TokenQueryParameterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                //if has request header, do nothing
                if (httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var authHeader) && authHeader.Any() &&
                    authHeader[0].StartsWith("Bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return;
                }

                var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
                var attribute = endpoint.Metadata.OfType<JwtParameterAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (attribute != null && httpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue(attribute.Parameter, out var param))
                {
                    var token = param.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                    {
                        httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Call the next middleware delegate in the pipeline 
                await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

The middleware is configured just before the Authorization and Authentication core.

```
app.UseMiddleware<TokenQueryParameterMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```